# Problems with Xcode 7.3 download

Tags: macbook-pro, xcode

I have a macbook air and I went to the store to install Xcode 7.3 and hit the Install App button, and a loading icon appeared but after waiting  20 min time nothing happened. I successfully installed one app from the store but I can't install Xcode.

What might be the problem?

What are the options to download it?

Comment: Xcode is about 4.5 GB. It will take a long time to come down, and I've noticed that it sometimes doesn't report download progress very well.

Comment: i started downloading this morning at 11:30 but it sill did nothing

Comment: so i tried again and again but it sill did nothing

Comment: do you have any other suggestion

Comment: This happens quite often with downloading Xcode.  Make sure you delete the incomplete download and then try again, preferably at a different time of day.  There's many variables that can impact this issue, such as your internet connection type, if you're on a wireless network, download congestion, etc.

Comment: i never even downloaded it i just need to update

Comment: You can't 'just update' Xcode, you need to download a new version.  The only options you have are to keep trying to download it from Apple or ask someone else (that you know) to download it and copy it from them.

Comment: In my case the button is labelled `Update` and not `DOWNLOAD`. The button switches to grey, clearly proving that an action has been understood, the spinning wheel rotate at full speed.

Comment: What is your version of MacOS X?

Comment: my version of Xcode is 7.2 and i want to update it to 7.3 i went to apple.com and it told me to update it on app store

Comment: fbara how do you delete the incomplete download